# Cython typdef for 2D array

Tags: types, macros, typedef, cython

I would like to use some sort of type declaration so that

```
def BlobExtraction(numpy.ndarray[dtype=uint8_t, ndim=2] pic):
```

could look more like

```
def BlobExtraction(greyimg pic):
```

I am using this type many times throughout the code. Can this be done better in Cython? I am not familiar with how typedef/ctypedef work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffer types as `numpy.ndarray[dtype=uint8_t, ndim=2]` are only allowed as function local variables, so you cannot do something like:

`ctypedef numpy.ndarray[dtype=uint8_t, ndim=2] myType`

in the global scope and keep calling it throgout the code.